# Will Tomcat maintain a MySql connection pool automatically ?

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, servlets, connection-pooling

I'm new to java servlet programming.

In my `doPost` method, I will do fetch data from mysql database and write something back. I know I should somehow use a connection pool to improve performance. But wondering how. Should I main a connection pool in my java code or **just need to config tomcat server**?

Can you give me some suggestions about how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. See the tomcat documentation [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) which describes how to configure MySQL DBCP (Database Connection Pool). 
Also you might consider setting up 'Preventing database connection pool leaks' configurations to reuse abandoned connections.

Comment: Since this document is for tomcat 6, is that same for 7?

Comment: And there is a document for [tomcat 7](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) if others searched this post.